# How to view the settings of a running UTM VM machine?

Tags: virtualization

In [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/), when a VM is running you cannot edit nor view settings. You have to shut down the VM to do this.

It would be very useful to see these settings on running VMs when configuring networks.

There is already an [issue on Github](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4220) about this.

Is there a way to get this settings from some files or with some commands ? This would be a workaround while waiting for a release containing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from perfect but you can either:

- look a the plist file in `~/Library/Containers/com.utmapp.UTM/Data/Documents/<vm_name.utm>/config.plist`.
- or look at the [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) command line with `ps aux | grep UTM`.